# What should be the presentation of $\mathbb Z$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation

> In the **Dummit-Foote** text the definition of relation and presentation (Group theory) are introduced as: [image]

In connection with the above definition I wounder what should be the presentation of $\mathbb Z$? Clearly enough here the generating set $S=\{1\}.$ But I'm clueless about the set of equation(s) $R_i$ in $\{1,0\}$ so that $\mathbb Z$ can be presented as:

$$\mathbb Z=\langle 1:R_i\rangle$$

Comment: It's an interesting error that you list the set of generators as a set, but indicate via indexing that the set of relations is a finite sequence of relations. That is a type error that also leads you to think the set of relations cannot be empty. It can be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\mathbb Z$ is the free group on one generator - free groups have generators but no relations. You could say that the set of relations is empty.

Comment: Note the distinction between a "free group" which has no relations, and a "free abelian group" which has just sufficient relations to ensure that the group is commutative. With one generator there is no difference, but with more than one the groups are very different.

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb Z$ is a free group with one generator. So $\mathbb Z$ has a single generator without any relation. In the formulation of Dummit-Foote, $m = 0$ and $$\mathbb Z = \langle \{a\} \mid \ \rangle.$$

Answer (score 3):

It's just $\mathbb{Z}=\langle z \mid \emptyset\rangle$

Comment: I think formally, it is not correct to write an empty set symbol.

Comment: I agree with azimut. Indeed, if $F$ is a free group on set $X$ , then $F=\langle X\mid~~~\rangle$

Comment: Glad to know that, thanks.